# Spring Websocket user login behavior

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

Can you help me to make clear one thing about WebSockets and Spring Security auth? I have an js client with websocket connection. When I load it for first time the user is unautharized and my spring server returns `undefined` in `frame.headers['user-name']` after websocket connect. Is it correct to make websocket reconnect on client side when user performs login/logout operations in sence to make websocket messaging authorized? The one thing is that after every connect client make some subscriptions and it sounds not good to make connect/disconnect and make new subcriptions every time. I hope you will help me and my question is clear. Sorry for my English. Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your application, is it possible to work without logging in?  In the application I work on, all users must be authenticated, so we only start a websocket connection after user login.  But, if your application allows both anonymous sessions and logged-in sessions, that wouldn't make sense for you.

Comment: I understood your approach. But some data should be sent asych from sceduler on server regardless of user authenticated or not @DavidMiller